# using JSON with variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, android, json, encode

I have been searching for a way to get the "values" from the database and insert them in JSON Response to an android application that receives ID ,Name and Email from PHP file
ID , Name , Email needs to be taken from database then sent as JSON response to Android Application here is my code and PHP file if you please tell me how to edit the PHP file so that it sends JSON with variables taken from database

MainActivity

```
package learn2crack.asynctask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import learn2crack.asynctask.library.JSONParser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView uid;
    TextView name1;
    TextView email1;
    Button Btngetdata;

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/JSON/";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";

    JSONArray user = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uid);
             name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
             email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                    // Getting JSON Array
                    user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

                    //Set JSON Data in TextView
                    uid.setText(id);
                    name1.setText(name);
                    email1.setText(email);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
    }

}
```

And PHP File

```
{
"user": [
{
"id": "001",
"name": "Raj Amal",
"email": "raj.amalw@gmail.com"
}
]
}
```

I Want it to be like this taking everything and assigning them to variable that i will call them later in android application

```
 <?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","pet_home");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='test' AND password='123'");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if($row_cnt>0){     
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
         $data = array('success'=>true, 'user'=>array("TAG_ID" => $row['id'], "TAG_NAME"=> $row['name'], "TAG_EMAIL" =>$row['email'])); 
     }else{
         $data = array('success'=>false);
     }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($data);



    mysqli_close($con);


    ?>
```

After doing this no response comes back to android app
Here is stacktrace seems like there is an exception

```
11-30 13:02:20.066: W/System.err(2854): org.json.JSONException: Value {"id":"OFF","TAG_EMAIL":"OFF","name":"OFF"} at user of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
11-30 13:02:20.066: W/System.err(2854):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
```

Comment: You might need to set content type header to 'application/json' before php output, something like header(....) and you can just use echo json_encode($user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, based on the `success` true or false you have check like user exist or not

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='test' AND password='123'");
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if($row_cnt>0){     
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
         $data = array('success'=>true, 'user'=>array("TAG_ID" => $row['id'], "TAG_NAME"=> $row['name'], "TAG_EMAIL" =>$row['email'])); 
     }else{
         $data = array('success'=>false);
     }
   echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: and set the HTTP header

Comment: thanks in advance i tried it but no response comes back and please hRoved tell what to do you mean by setting the HTTP header ?

Comment: Can you run this PHP file in browser and check what is the response you get from browser

Comment: there is no data in users table, can you in your table w

Comment: just checked username exist and password matches

Comment: did you run this query, SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='test' AND password='123' in your phpmyadmin or cmd prompt

Comment: i also set num of rows as constant equals 1 to see if it works 
it actually works here 
{"success":true,"user":{"TAG_ID":"XML","TAG_NAME":"MO","TAG_EMAIL":"MO@"}}

Comment: still not getting response on android app

Comment: check my post again i posted a stacktrace seems like there is an exception don't know what does it mean